# Explicit Songs in Apple Music are Censored

Tags: iphone, apple-music, ios

I've never had this issue when purchasing music from the iTunes Store, but Apple Music is weird. For some songs, after adding the explicit version to my library and downloading for offline play, it still only plays the clean version. However, the 'E' badge still shows up next to the song name, and explicit songs are enabled in Restrictions.

Comment: I haven't had that happen, can you share specific song titles where this has happened? Do you have explicit tracks enabled in Settings, Music?